# Conditional update SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update my third column value (option_value) with my database and code below:

[image: database]

```
if(isset($_POST['settings_updatebtn']))
{
    $finerate= $_POST['fine_rate'];
    $issue_email = $_POST['issue_template'];
    $return_email = $_POST['return_template'];

    $query = "UPDATE
                settings
            SET
                option_value = CASE option_name WHEN 'finerate' THEN '$finerate' WHEN 'email_temp_issue' THEN '$issue_email' WHEN 'email_temp_return' THEN '$return_email'
            WHERE
                option_name IN (
                'finerate',
                'email_temp_issue',
                'email_temp_return'
                )";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['success']= "Your settings is updated";
        header('Location: systemsettings.php');    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status']= "Your settings is NOT updated";
        header('Location: systemsettings.php');    }
}
```

However it shows query not running, is my SQL statement wrong in somewhere?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: what's the error you receive?

Comment: @AbhinK showing status: Your settings is NOT updated. The query did not run

Comment: @treyBake what should I write to stop the SQL injection?

Comment: @CarolH refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `END` at the end of your [case statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp):

```
UPDATE
    settings
SET
    option_value = 
        CASE option_name 
            WHEN 'finerate' THEN '$finerate' 
            WHEN 'email_temp_issue' THEN '$issue_email' 
            WHEN 'email_temp_return' THEN '$return_email'
        END
WHERE
    option_name IN (
    'finerate',
    'email_temp_issue',
    'email_temp_return'
    )
```

Comment: this code is open to SQL injection and should be amended according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)